# What is the purpose of creating a bare git repo compared to non-bare?

Tags: git

I understand that a bare git repo does not contain a working tree meaning that its not possible to add, commit, status etc.

But why would one NOT want that? If you have a remote company truth repo I understand the idea that its not to be worked in directly but it would give more flexibility to actually create it as a non-bare so why not do that?

Comment: it saves disk space and makes the server admin easier.

Comment: ok but from a functional perspective I would get the same by creating a non-bare repo?

Comment: You will need to either disable pushing to the currently checked out branch or suffer the annoying consequences - but there are no other practical differences I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this tutorial](http://bitflop.com/tutorials/git-bare-vs-non-bare-repositories.html) and starting with git 1.7.0, to allow a remote push, a git repository must be bare.

Comment: Unfortunately the person who wrote that blog post doesn't seem to have a very good understanding of Git, and makes a number of mis-statements, including the one you quote.

Comment: I have read that same article. I am having a hard time understanding it, and it also has a broken link at the bottom.